# pytest "No module named" error

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I'm new to python and trying to write a test for my first app.
simple app structure:

```
- app
      - tests
        __init__.py
        - test_main.py
      - __init__.py
      - main.py
```

The `main.py` contains  `main_func`

**test_main.py:**

```
from main import main_func

def test_check():
    assert main_func() is True
```

If i run the test manually, by the command `pytest` while in `app` directory - got this **error:**

```
C:\Users\*****\PycharmProjects\checker3>pytest
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.0.3, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: C:\Users\*****\PycharmProjects\app, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors 

=================================== ERRORS ====================================
_____________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_main.py _____________________
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\*****\PycharmProjects\app\tests\test_main.py'.
Original error message:
'No module named 'main''
Make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.14 seconds ===========================
```

the packages names are right. Also, i use the `PyCharm` IDE and it doesn't track any import package error.

Moreover, when i execute the pytest test configuration through the IDE - test is working.

Comment: You need an empty `__init__.py` in the `tests` folder.

Comment: i had, removed. Just added now - nothing changed

Comment: worked like a charm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it runs in pycharm because of folder configuration mark in pycharm project. If you set the app folder as "Source" in settings, pycharm can include in any path.

For details;
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html

It doesn't run in shell because it cannot include main. If you want to include and run, you should insert app path in sys.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, <app folder path>)
```

Comment: right, i did that.
there is no issue with running it through pycharm. The prob is why it doesn't run just via `pytest` command

Comment: I added detail how can you run test in shell.